# Doxygen: wrong function name in the documentation (C)

Tags: c, doxygen

I've got functions defined as follows:

```
#define FUNC(rettype, memclass) rettype

/// @brief a function.
/// @param param a function parameter.
FUNC(void, PUBLIC_CTX) my_fun1(int* param);

/// @brief a function.
FUNC(int, PUBLIC_CTX) my_fun2(void);
```

but when generating doxygen documentation all the functions are named as FUNC instead of my_fun1, my_fun2.
Is there a way to make doxygen take the right function name?

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using (`doxygen -v`? What are your settings for doxygen different from the default settings (`doxygen -x Doxyfile`)? Did you look at e.g. the setting `MACRO_EXPANSION` (and the other settings possible, see the paragraph "Configuration options related to the preprocessor".

Comment: You have to configure Doxygen to expand macros, see ENABLE_PREPROCESSING, MACRO_EXPANSION and maybe EXPAND_ONLY_PREDEF.

Comment: You could use `@fn` to add the prototype "manually".